# how to write search result of hadoop commands to a file

Tags: unix, hadoop

I want to fetch only filenames from a directory in hadoop and save it to a different location in hadoop or local machine.I have more than 1000files in the folder and i want to know the name of the files.
I tried the below comand but i am unable to save it to a location.

for filename in `hadoop fs -ls /base/base1 | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .json$ | tr '\n' ' '`; do echo $filename; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hadoop fs -ls /base/base1 | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .json$ | tr '\n' ' ' > somefile.txt`

Comment: thanks for the immediate response.I tried this already but the result is like /base/base1/file1.json /base/base1/file2.json /base/base1/file3.json and so on.May be i should add a space break or something along with this to solve this

Comment: Finally got the solution as hadoop fs -stat "%n" /base/base1/* >output1.txt